# Como verificar ficheiros duplicados?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Como é que posso verificar se dois ficheiros são iguais, mesmo que o nome seja diferente numa aplicação node js?

Comment: Faça um hash entre os arquivos.

Comment: A idéia de usar hashes tem problemas. Hash não garante identidade, só garante não-identidade se os hashes forem diferentes. E para calcular o hash você tem que ler o arquivo todo, se é para ler o arquivo todo basta comparar o conteúdo original - calcular o hash (mesmo que garantisse qualquer coisa, o que não é verdade) é um esforço desnecessário. É admissível somente em casos onde você pode aceitar uma margem (por mais que ínfima) de erro, e que justifique a não leitura (que a leitura tenha custo, seja de dados ou tempo, como comparação remota) e já tenha um dos hashes armazenado.

Comment: Sobre o fechamento, é importante sempre detalhar melhor a dificuldade encontrada, uma descrição do que tentou e o que impediu de avançar ajuda bastante. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das formas é comparando a hash criptográfica de cada um dos arquivos, se eles forem iguais é porque o arquivo é idêntico.

Para isto você pode usar o [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm) e o [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) para abrir o arquivo.

Criei uma função:

```
function CriarHash(Texto){

    return Hash.createHash('sha512').update(Texto).digest('hex');

}
```

Para criar as Hashes, neste caso em SHA-2 de 512 bits, *você pode usar outros da família SHA-2 ou até mesmo da SHA-3 ou utilizar o BLAKE2*.

Também criei uma função para abrir cada arquivo e criar uma hash de cada um e retornar todas as *hashes*:

```
function CriarHashArquivos(NomeArquivos){

    ArquivosHashes = [];

    NomeArquivos.forEach(function(Nome) {

        ArquivosHashes.push(CriarHash( Arquivo.readFileSync(Nome)));

    });

    return ArquivosHashes;

}
```

Assim o que precisa fazer é apenas verificar se todas as *hashes* são iguais, para isto criei isto:

```
function HashIgual(Hashes){

    return Hashes.every( v => v === Hashes[0])

}
```

> **/!\** Isto não é *Timing attack safe*, isto está vulnerável a ataques do tipo *timming attack*, não sei se o NodeJS possui alguma função nativa de comparação que seja protegida a isto.

No final terá isto:

```
var Hash = require('crypto');
var Arquivo = require('fs');

function CriarHashArquivos(NomeArquivos){

    ArquivosHashes = [];

    NomeArquivos.forEach(function(Nome) {

        ArquivosHashes.push(CriarHash( Arquivo.readFileSync(Nome)));

    });

    return ArquivosHashes;

}

function CriarHash(Texto){

    return Hash.createHash('sha512').update(Texto).digest('hex');

}

function HashIgual(Hashes){

    return Hashes.every( v => v === Hashes[0])

}
```

Para utilizar basta definir os arquivos, por exemplo:

```
var NomesDosArquivos = ['arquivo1.txt', 'arquivo2.txt'];

console.log( HashIgual( CriarHashArquivos(NomesDosArquivos) ) );
```

Ele irá retornar `true` se todos os arquivos forem iguais ou `false` se ao menos um dos arquivos comparados forem diferentes.

---

O NodeJS, até onde pesquisei, não possui uma função que seja Timing Attack Safe, portanto se quiser utilizar uma comparação mais segura, utilize, **por exemplo**:

```
function HashIgual(Hashes){

    eIgual = 0;

    Hashes.forEach(function(HashArquivo){

        for (var i = 0; i < HashArquivo.length; ++i) {
            eIgual |= (HashArquivo.charCodeAt(i) ^ Hashes[0].charCodeAt(i));
        }

    });

    return eIgual;

}
```

Isso irá executar um `XOR` que irá fazer o tempo de execução ser igual em qualquer caso, ao contrário da comparação de `==` e `===`. Neste seu caso especifico não vejo a necessidade de utiliza-lo, mas se for, por exemplo, comparar senhas sempre utilize funções *constant-time*. ;)

<sub><sub>PS: Não tenho muito conhecimento em NodeJS.</sub></sub>